# Play Framework: How to get the current request in a custom BodyParser

Tags: scala, playframework

Given the following body parser that saves incoming files into MongoDB...

```
fsBodyParser()(
  implicit gridFsService: GridFsService
): BodyParser[MultipartFormData[Future[MetaFile]]] = {
  import BodyParsers.parse._

  multipartFormData(
    Multipart.handleFilePart {
      case Multipart.FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>
        gridFsService.iteratee(filename, contentType)
    }
  ) 
}

...

def saveFile = SecureAction.async(fsBodyParser) { implicit request =>

  ...
}
```

how do I get the current request in `fsBodyParser`?